Selenium python firefox запуск для другого python скрипта
Имеется питон скрипт вида
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("-headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(site)

В скрипт передаётся site который потом открывается в firefox.
Передать сразу набор сайтов не выйдет как следствие каждый раз при запуске скрипта создаётся новый драйвер и закрывается на что тратится куча времени.
Возможно ли как то предварительно ( может в другом скрипте ) создать драйвер и передать в используемый скрипт? Что бы осталось только вызвать
driver.get(site)

Не создавая каждый раз новый драйвер и тем самым значительно увеличивая скорость работы.
А по завершению закрыть драйвер.

Предложу такое простое решение, не проверял работоспособность:
def create_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("-headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    return driver

def open_site(driver, site):
    driver.get(site)

def close_driver(driver):
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = create_driver()

    sites = ["https://example.com", "https://another-site.com", "https://yet-another-site.com"]

    for site in sites:
        open_site(driver, site)
        # Здесь можно добавить ожидание, обработку страницы, и так далее
    
    close_driver(driver)


Передавать сразу все сайты нет возможности в этом и затык. За раз приходит только 1 сайт как следствие предложенный вариант ничем не будет отличаться. Нужно что бы драйвер создавался отдельно ( можно вызвать перед началом работ ) - использовался многократно когда кончаются запросы - закрывался.

@Дмитрий не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос. Через что подаются запросы и как происходит понимание, когда они заканчиваются? Почему нет возможности сначала собрать все запросы, а потом обработать?

запросы приходят из вне по http ( из браузера клиента ) и ожидают ответ. Собрать - можно но как вернуть результат потом неясно ведь поток из браузера будет упорно ждать ответа.

@Дмитрий в таком случае нужен какой нибудь асинхронный фреймворк, по типу FastAPI. При старте приложения вызывается create_driver(), асинхронные запросы обрабатываются с помощью асинхронного метода и после выполнения запроса браузер может продолжать работу, и сервер сразу возвращает ответ.
